# Get data from the excel file using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to load data using following code.

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(uploadExcelFile.PostedFile.FileName);
            string connString = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Rizwan shahid\\Desktop\\DataUpload\\Req.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
            OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                oledbConn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbConn);
                OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                oleda.Fill(ds, "Table");
                return ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                oledbConn.Close();
            }
```

It was working on 32Bit operating system but when run this code on 64Bit OS it gives the following error

```
The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.
```

I am running VS in Administrator mode and found many solution like replace Sheet1 with file name or place file in C drive but still getting the same error.

Comment: catch
{
    return null;
}    Really?  Aren't you concerned with what the error is?

Comment: @SteveWellens do u know about my issue?

Comment: I have heard/read of *some* instances of this issue arising if the source .xls file is, somehow, not available, open, locked, otherwise inaccessible...although ideally you would/should get a different message if this were the case. Just a thought, probably a longshot...are we sure the xls file is in the same/right location on the 64-bit box?

Comment: @SteveWellens do u know about my issue? – user1387147    Yes, I read your post.  Then I made a comment about your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can download latest version here of Jet

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=jet

Answer (score 0):

This works (I start out with a 'dummy' path and then apply the real runtime path):

```
OleStringBuilder =
        new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';");

OleStringBuilder.DataSource = MapPath(@"~\App_Data\MyExcelWorksheet.xls");
```